# Cannot find name 'SP'.ts(2304)

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, dialog

I am using following function to display url in the Model popup in sharepoint.

```js
function openDialog(pageUrl) { 
          SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog( 
            { 
              url: pageUrl, 
              width: 700, 
              height: 700, 
              title: "Office Holidays" 
            } 
          ); 
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="openDialog('https://stackoverflow.com')"> Click Me</button>
```

but It's giving me an error at SP namespace when I used same function in the SPFX using react.

Is there anything I need to install or import?

Comment: need more info. some context.

Comment: This is the javascript function which displays Model Dialog which I want to use into the typescript but when I tried to convert function into the ts it's giving me an error at SP namespace -> http://definitelytyped.org/docs/sharepoint--SharePoint/classes/sp.ui.modaldialog.html

Comment: pageUrl: any... pls type it string, dont use any. And post what error you get. maybe you are missing import? or some type is wrong. need to see error what you get

Comment: sorry for making confused, I have updated my question

Comment: this SP. its define how? its imported as module? or you are using some script link <script href="url to SP UI library" /> ?

Comment: It's automatically gets available in the sharepont site

Comment: ok well i dont know sharepoint. if noone will get you correct solution ou can use just custom declaration to avoid this error. declare const SP: any;  This is really bad solution. hope someone will come with something smart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample demo:
[image]

```
import { SPComponentLoader } from '@microsoft/sp-loader';
declare var SP:any;
```

load necessary js and css

```
SPComponentLoader.loadCss('/_layouts/15/1033/styles/corev15.css');  

    SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/init.js', {
      globalExportsName: '$_global_init'
    })
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
      return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js', {
        globalExportsName: 'Sys'
      });
    })
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
      return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/ScriptResx.ashx?name=sp.res&culture=en-us', {
        globalExportsName: 'Sys'
      });
    })
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
      return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js', {
        globalExportsName: 'SP'
      });
    })
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
      return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/SP.js', {
        globalExportsName: 'SP'
      });
    })
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
      return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/sp.init.js', {
        globalExportsName: 'SP'
      });
    })        
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
      return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/sp.ui.dialog.js', {
        globalExportsName: 'SP'
      });
    });
```

bind event.

```
this.domElement.innerHTML = `
      <div class="${ styles.fixWebpart }">
        <div class="${ styles.container }">
          <div class="${ styles.row }">
            <div class="${ styles.column }">
              <span class="${ styles.title }">Welcome to SharePoint!</span>
              <p class="${ styles.subTitle }">Customize SharePoint experiences using web parts.</p>
              <p class="${ styles.description }">${escape(this.properties.description)}</p>            
              <input id="myButton" type="button" value="Click me" />                                  
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>`

    this.domElement.querySelector('#myButton').addEventListener('click', () => { this.MyNotify(); });
```

event

```
public MyNotify():void{      

  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog( 
    { 
      url: '/sites/lee/Lists/ListB/AllItems.aspx', 
      width: 700, 
      height: 700, 
      title: "Office Holidays" 
    } 
  );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks just wanted to add something into your answer. If we run the SPFx Webpart in sharepoint context then we don't need the all javascript loaded into the webpart as it is by default available in sharepoint site.

Comment: @Lee_MSFT, I have tried your code in my application, but I am getting SP is not defined error. I am getting the button call event into function.

Comment: @MAC just declare it like as "declare var SP:any;".